# C2DM registrationId in emulator after restart

Tags: android, android-c2dm

After some fits and starts, I've gotten Android C2DM working in the emulator. The first time the app launches, it registers with the C2DM service, using code from the [chrometophone project](https://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/). The `registrationId` is saved in the preferences, and used on subsequent launches.

This seems to work just fine launch to launch, **as long as the emulator keeps running**. However, if I kill the emulator and restart it, then the app requires a new registration to start receiving C2DM messages again. Is this known/expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is known/expected behaviour. [Item 2 in Enabling C2DM](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/#register) reads:

> *If the registration is successful, the C2DM server broadcasts a
>   REGISTRATION Intent which gives the application a registration ID. The
>   application should store this ID for later use. **Note that Google may
>   periodically refresh the registration ID**, so you should design your
>   application with the understanding that the REGISTRATION Intent may be
>   called multiple times. Your application needs to be able to respond
>   accordingly.*

I found that the registration ID changes quite often. I also found that even after the registration ID changes, older ones may still work for some time.